# PowerShell to move subitems of multiple folders into their own subfolders

Tags: powershell, subdirectory

I'm working on a project cleaning up a file server's folder redirection folders. Would like to ask for some help with a PS script that would move the files in user folders into new "Documents" sub-folders, as we're facing manually performing this for a lot of profiles.

A tree example currently looks like:

```
―FolderRedirection
―――JContoso
――――――File.docx
――――――File.pptx
―――MDerby
――――――File.docx
――――――File.pptx
```

I'd like to be able to achieve:

```
―FolderRedirection
―――JContoso
――――――Documents
―――――――――File.docx
―――――――――File.pptx
―――MDerby
――――――Documents
―――――――――File.docx
―――――――――File.pptx
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, bear in mind for future questions you should provide at least a minimal attempt at solving the problem.

The inline comments should help you with the code logic.

```
# get all folders in `FolderRedirection`
foreach($dir in Get-ChildItem .\FolderRedirection -Directory) {
    # create a new `Documents` folder in each sub folder
    $dest = $dir | Join-Path -ChildPath Documents
    $dest = New-Item $dest -ItemType Directory -Force
    # get all files in each folder and move them to the new folder
    $dir | Get-ChildItem -File | Move-Item -Destination $dest
}
```